# Assuming many variables at once

Tags: maple

I'm trying to set up the following constraints:

`assume(E1A::integer,E2A::integer,...,E2B::integer,...,E3C::integer)`

`additionally(E1A>=0,E2A>=0,...,E3C>=0)`

`additionally(E1A<=3,E2A<=3,...,E3C<=3)`

is there any way to do this without typing out all the terms `E1A, E2A,...,E3C`? I tried doing

`for i from 0 to 3 do (assume(EiA::integer)) end do`

as a shortcut, but Maple didn't like that, presumably because it didn't view the `i` as an indexing variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can form names by concatenation.

```
restart:

assume( seq( cat(`E`,i,`A`)::integer, i=1..3 ) );
```

And now, to test,

```
[ seq( cat(`E`,i,`A`), i=1..3 ) ]:
map( about, % ):

  Originally E1A, renamed E1A~:
    is assumed to be: integer

  Originally E2A, renamed E2A~:
    is assumed to be: integer

  Originally E3A, renamed E3A~:
    is assumed to be: integer
```

You can also nest `seq`, eg,

```
restart:
assume( seq( seq( cat(`E`,i,abc)::integer, i=1..3), abc=[A,B,C] ) );

[ seq( seq( cat(`E`,i,abc), i=1..3), abc=[A,B,C] ) ]:
map( about, % ):
```

Answer (score 1):

With the elementwise operator and the concatenation operator you can get all your assuming down to one line:

```
assume(E||(1..3)||A ::~ AndProp(integer, RealRange(0,3)));
```